# why all winform uicontrol update when PropertyChangedEvent only raise once in datasource？

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a winform appli
Window which has two textBoxs(textbox1,textbox2).
For this window, There is a class Form1ViewModel.cs which contains two properties Number1 and Number2 as below:

```
public class Form1ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SynchronizationContext _uiContext;
    public Form1ViewModel(SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext)
    {
        _uiContext = synchronizationContext;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int _number1;
    public int Number1
    {
        get { return _number1; }
        set
        {
            _number1 = value;
            SafeInvoke(() => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Number1")));
        }
    }
    private int _number2 = 10;
    public int Number2
    {
        get { return _number2; }
        set { _number2 = value; }
    }
    private void SafeInvoke(Action action)
    {
        _uiContext.Post(s => action(), null);
    }
    public void StartIncrease()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Number1++;
                Number2++;

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After form1 loaded,I do the following things:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form1ViewModel Form1ViewModel;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += Form1_Load;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1ViewModel = new Form1ViewModel(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current);
        this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Form1ViewModel, "Number1");
        this.textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", Form1ViewModel, "Number2");
        Form1ViewModel.StartIncrease();
    }
}
```

What I feel so strange is that after I Invoke the StartIncrease method,Property Number2 dose not raise PropertyChanged event.But In Form1,we could see that the text of textbox2 would also change every 1 second. Is there any way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: That's simple, direct Binding. Try to bind that class to a DataGridView instead (which you have to bind through a BindingSource). What happens then?

Comment: BTW, do yourself a favor, add a CancellationTokenSource and implement IDisposable in that class. When the Dispose method is called, you call the `Cancel()` and `Dispose()` methods of the CTS. In `StartIncrease()` you can add `CancellationToken? token = [Your CTS]?.Token;` and in the loop `if (token != null && token.Value.IsCancellationRequested) break;` -- Also, possibly change `public async Task StartIncrease()`. Then you can run a Task and `await Task.Delay(1000);`. Or don't run a Task either.

Comment: Have you tryed to call "StartIncrease" on Form_SHOW instead?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is easy to reproduce with a [Minimal Reproducible Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that removes the synchronization, Task, and the timer loop. This makes it easier observe that whether you're updating with a timer or a button, you *are changing* the value of the backing store of `Number2`. Regardless of whether you fire a property change or not, WinOS can call the getter it *any* time it sees fit in order to redraw `textBox2` using the last known value of the backing store. In other words, firing the `PropertyChanged` notification ensures that this getter will be called (and the `TextBox` refreshed with the latest value), but *not* firing it is no guarantee that it won't!

```
public class Form1ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int _number1;
    public int Number1
    {
        get { return _number1; }
        set
        {
            if (_number1 != value)
            {
                _number1 = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                    this, 
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Number1)));
            }
        }
    }
    private int _number2 = 10;
    public int Number2
    {
        get { return _number2; }
        set
        {
            if (_number2 != value)
            {
                _number2 = value;
                // Comment/Uncomment this notifier to show lag
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                    this, 
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Number2)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Perform *minimal binding only* during the `Load` event:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Form1ViewModel = new Form1ViewModel();
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Form1ViewModel, "Number1");
    textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", Form1ViewModel, "Number2");
}
```

The behavior can be demonstrated by clicking a button.

```
private void buttonIncrease_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1ViewModel.Number1++;
    Form1ViewModel.Number2++;
}
```

Commenting out the property change notification for the `Number2` property and clicking the test button makes it clear WinOS is coming to get that value in the process of redrawing the textboxes in response to the notified change in `Number1`, and does so whether you like it or not. If the data binding contract for `Number2` is broken by commenting out the notify code, the `textBox2` value always lags by one in the UI because when `Number2` *really* changes (in the following line) the UI isn't being notified:

**Notify code is commented out**

[image: Shows lag]

**Notify is allowed**

[image]

Bottom line, one must assume that `textbox2` can be redrawn at any time, and that the getter for its bound property will be called in the process.